# How to start multiple process in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, start-process

How does one start a process or program simultaneously?

Such as to open 5 notepads with one cmdlet?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: the thing is that i remember that i've used start-process ( i need it for testing) but i don't remember how i did it with one liner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via `Start-Process`, examples and docu can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6).

```
1..5 | % { Start-Process notepad.exe}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i think that there is an option not to use for-eachobject

Comment: @WebsGhost - you will need SOME sort of loop construct. [*grin*] that one is the simplest. not the fastest, but the number is low enuf that the speed lost using a pipeline & `ForEach-Object` is not meaningful.